# Can demons possess dead bodies?

Tags: plot-explanation, supernatural

In *Supernatural* season 15 episode 1, Jack's dead body is possessed by the demon Belphegor.

Has this happened before in *Supernatural*? I didn't think that demons could possess dead bodies.

Comment: One thing to remember - this doesn't have to follow normal rules. God (well, Chuck) is now manipulating events, bringing the dead back to life and instantly making it night in a small area. For all we (currently) know, he may have "written" Belphegor possessing Jack's corpse.

Answer (score 1):

Both demons and angels can possess a dead body. Though for angels its more unlikely, as they need the permission.

From https://supernatural.fandom.com/wiki/Vessels:

> Both angels and demons can inhabit a dead person though given that
>   angels need their vessel's permission, this is likely unique to
>   Castiel as he was resurrected by God in the body of Jimmy Novak while
>   Jimmy was not brought back. Lucifer, after being exorcised from
>   Jefferson Rooney, was sent back into Nick's body by Crowley's
>   perverted spell. While Nick's body had been repaired and improved to
>   act as Lucifer's permanent vessel, Nick did not appear to have
>   reconsented despite having been resurrected. This was presumably due
>   to the nature of the spell modifications Crowley performed.

I am pretty sure that we had seens demons possess dead bodies before, but I can't quite remember and couldn't find any other hint to it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes they can. Remember the Ruby played by Genevieve Padalecki? According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_(Supernatural))

> To appease Sam, who dislikes her using a living host against the
>   host's will, Ruby takes possession of a body recently declared to be
>   **dead** (Genevieve Cortese).

I'm sure there are other examples too, like Castiel still being able to possess Jimmy Novak's body after it had been destroyed at a molecular level by Lucifer (5.22), the fact being confirmed in season 10. Also, Sam and Dean tried to kill a woman possessed by a demon in season 1 by throwing her out of the window yet she still got up because the demon was still alive in her.